# Why does my ajax call not returning my data from controller?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core

I'm having a hard time getting the data from client but my code on visual studio when I'm on a breakpoint it gets the data but I cant receive it on my browser.

Here's my AJAX call

```
function GetRecord() {
    var elemEmployee = 55;
    var startDT = $('#searchFilterStartDate').val();
    var endDT = $('#searchFilterEndDate').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Modules/GetDTRRecord",
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            EmployeeID: elemEmployee,
            DateFrom: endDT,
            DateTo: startDT,
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {


            console.log('Data Success ');

             console.log(data);


        }
    });
}
```

here's my controller:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public List<DTRRecordList.Entity> GetDTRRecord(DTRRecordList.Entity data)
        {
            var entity = new DTRRecordList();
         
            return entity.GetDTR(data);
        }
```

As you can see below I got 38 records but I can't receive it on my js even that `console.log('Data Success')` is not shown on my console.
[image: As you can see here I got records]
[image]

Comment: You can also handle `error` instead of just `success`.

Comment: try removing `dataType: "json",` in your js, may be return value is not json.  also you have `data` in your GET request, and also passing same name for function that is for success result handler, change input argument name and try.

Comment: @Crowcoder yeah, nothing got into console still.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran what do you mean? I should change variable name on my `success: function(data){}` ?

Comment: Are there no other errors in the console? What does the response look like from the network pane of the browser dev tools?

Comment: @Crowcoder I don't have anything on Fetch/XHR section

Comment: What does your `GetDTR` method do - just because there are 38 records in `entity`, I assume you're then doing some filtering based on the EmployeeId and Date Range - are they valid for the dataset you have?

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid `GetDTR` is method for my SQL SP transaction.

Comment: If you are in Chrome have you turned on "preserve log"? Maybe you are doing both an xhr and a postback because you are using a submit action button?

Comment: Yeah there's an XHR failed here https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIab2.png

Comment: Don't filter network on just xhr. If you are triggering a form submission it will be a document request

Comment: @Crowcoder https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3ghk.png

Comment: That is what happens when you do whatever you do to hit your controller? Looks like you are doing a submit but you probably have to show the top of that stack to see it. Return `false` from the javascript function that does the ajax request and see what happens.

Comment: I find your `GetDTRRecord`  is `Get` method, you can mock data in your method, then test.

Comment: @Jason How ?I don’t know what you mean brother

Comment: @JohnPhillipAbello Pls paste the url to the broswer, like `https://localhost:44339/Modules/GetDTRRecord?params=` to check this api interface.

Comment: @JohnPhillipAbello The expect behavior should be list the entity data in the page.

Comment: Nothing happens. Yes I expect to have an array to log unto console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return `JSON` from your `Controller` method. You can change your method to:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetDTRRecord(DTRRecordList.Entity data)
    {
        var entity = new DTRRecordList();
        var getDTR= entity.GetDTR(data);
        return Json(new {dtrData= getDTR});
    }
```

And in your `Ajax` call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Modules/GetDTRRecord",
    type: "GET",
    data: {
        EmployeeID: elemEmployee,
        DateFrom: endDT,
        DateTo: startDT,
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
         console.log('Data Success ');
         console.log(data.dtrData);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
});
```

After a discussion with O.P and seeing the code, it was found that the issue was happening because the `form` submit was happening which was causing the page to reload twice. After removing the form event and adding the click event in:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //On Clink "Search Button"
    $("#searchbtn").click(
    function () { GetRecord(); });
});
```

The data seems to be coming as expected.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran No, this should work. `return new Json`  does not make sense.

Comment: I'm having `The name JsonRequestBehavior does not exist in the current context`

Comment: nope , I have using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

Comment: @JohnPhillipAbello You did not mention that in your question and also there were not tags for asp.netcore. `JsonRequestBehavior` has been deprecated in ASP.NET Core. You can remove that option and try.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not notice I put a wrong tag, well as I tried, still nothing happens, console is not showing anything

Comment: @JohnPhillipAbello Are you looking in the right option on the browser console under user messages? I have also added `error` block in your `Ajax` call. See if you seeing any errors there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241790/discussion-between-john-phillip-abello-and-rahul-sharma).